# Is there a way to use MyBatis with the Play! framework?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, mybatis

First of all, Kudos \m/ on selecting the best Java web framework...
Since we have good Oracle PL/SQL developers, we want to ditch the default JPA plugin and use MyBatis instead. I checked the repo and currently there is no module for it. Could someone please shed the light for us on how to do it? Also, will it work with the CRUD module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a helper class like this one:

```
public class DBSession {

    public SqlSession openSession() throws IOException {
        SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = getFactory();
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    private SqlSessionFactory getFactory() throws IOException {
        String resource = "mybatis/conf/ibatis.xml";
        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
        SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Notice the "mybatis/conf/ibatis.xml" string that refers to MyBatis configuration. For better performance I think you may want to cache the getFactory result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Play 2.0 you can use mybatis-scala directly, no module needed. Look at this complete example:

http://www.fdmtech.org/2012/03/a-better-example-of-play-framework-2-0-with-mybatis-for-scala-beta/

Answer (score 0):

I'm no MyBatis expert, but unless it uses standard JPA annotations it proably won't work with the CRUD module.

On how to do it, create a Play plugin and use the [EBeans](http://www.playframework.org/modules/ebean) one as inspiration on how to implement it, as it tackles a similar issue.